# Как правильней использовать return c колбэком?

Tags: javascript

Как правильней всего использовать `return` с колбэк-функцей в javascript?

```
// вариант №1
function func(callback) {

  // ...

  callback();
}


// вариант №2
function func(callback) {

  // ...

  callback();
  return;
}


// вариант №3
function func(callback) {

  // ...

  return callback();
}
```

Сам использую вариант №3. С проверкой на функцию.

Comment: В данном случае как вам больше нравится.

Answer (score 3):

Как правило, коллбеки вызываются в асинхронных функциях. Немного изменим пример:

```js
function f1(callback) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    callback(null, 1);
  });
}

function f2(callback) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    callback(null, 2);
    return;
  });
}

function f3(callback) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    return callback(null, 3);
  });
}

function handle(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log(data);
  }
}

f1(handle);
f2(handle);
f3(handle);
```

Очевидно, что все `return` абсолютно бесполезны и не влияют на результат.

А теперь взглянем на функцию `handle`:

```
function handle(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

Хочется её немного переписать, чтобы основная её задача - обрабатывать `data` не находилась в ветке else:

```
function handle(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }

  console.log(data);
}
```

Хм.. Выглядит знакомо? Но как-то длинновато два оператора для тупой обработки ошибки - что если сократить?

```
function handle(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }

  console.log(data);
}
```

Ну вот и с коллбеками так же:

```js
function hasError() {
  return Math.random() < .5;
}

function f1(callback) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    if (hasError()) {
      callback(new Error(1));
    } else {
      callback(null, 1);
    }
  });
}

function f2(callback) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    if (hasError()) {
      callback(new Error(2));
      return;
    }
    
    callback(null, 2);
  });
}

function f3(callback) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    if (hasError()) {
      return callback(new Error(3));
    }
    
    callback(null, 3);
  });
}

function handle(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err.message);
  }
  
  console.log(data);
}

f1(handle);
f2(handle);
f3(handle);
```

Лично мне нравится вариант с `return callback()`, поскольку он короче, но не надо совать return туда, где он не нужен. Но ещё стоит отметить, что если возвращаемое значение где-то используется, то не стоит использовать третий вариант, поскольку таким образом будет отдаваться значение, возвращённое коллбеком вместо undefined. Не стоит рассчитывать, что коллбэк всегда возвращает undefined, если его возвращаемое значение тебе не нужно.

Comment: увидев в коде return callback(), я в первую очередь подумаю, что функция **возвращает** осмысленный результат. А по факту это не так. Лучше заменить `if (err) {` на `if (НЕ err) {` и обрабатывать ошибку в ветке else, как и хотелось.

Comment: Обычно обработка ошибки сводится к её передае в коллбэк - т. е. одна строка. Более короткую ветвь принято писать первой. А вот увеличивать уровень вложенности нерационально, потому что после вызова коллбэка с ошибкой делать уже нечего, так что return. Ну и довольно часто их объединяют. Как-то мне это не кажется неожиданным :)

Comment: @tilin, добавил в конец уточнение по поводу возвращаемого значения.

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понятно, что вы имеете ввиду под возвратом колбэк функции, но варианты 1 и 2 иденичны и вернут undefined. Вариант 3 вернет результат вызова функции callback.

```js
function func1(callback) {
  callback();
}

function func2(callback) {
  callback();
  return;
}

function func3(callback) {
  return callback();
}   

console.log(func1(()=>1));
console.log(func2(()=>1));
console.log(func3(()=>1));
```

Comment: Конечно же я имел ввиду именно вызов. Не совсем корректно задал вопрос.

Comment: Думаю, ты не в ту сторону стал копать. Вопрос скорее про способ заершения функции, по крайней мере, это наиболее частое место, где возможны эти 3 конструкции.